# Adding symbolic breakpoint to local code

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I've an Xcode project (let's call it A) that has dependency on .a library. The .a library code has also been compiled locally in a different Xcode (let's call it B) project. I want to now debug B's code while running A project.

I've added symbolic breakpoint to B's code. However, I want the breakpoint to be able to actually open B's code - but it only opens symbolicated code[see figure]. How can make Xcode open the actual B's code while debugging, given the code is available locally.

[image: symbolicated breakpoint hit]

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can! well the scenario is that Yes you can debug both or any one of them but make sure that both device are different example:
1- one project is running on simulator and other on connected device.
2- you can run both project on different simulator device